# Fix a newsletter code to work properly in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, newsletter

I'm asking for help to fix the code of a newsletter to work properly in Outlook desktop. It work great in other emails, even in outlook mobile. In outlook desktop is messes up most of the newsletter. I'm also open to other suggestions of creating newsletters to work properly in outlook desktop.

Here's the code:

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
body {
    Margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
.webkit {
    max-width: 600px;
}
.outer {
    Margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
}
.full-width-image img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: auto;
}
.inner {
    padding: 10px;
}
p {
    Margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.h1 {
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    Margin-top: 15px;
    Margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    Margin-top: 10px;
    Margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.one-column .contents {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.one-column p {
    font-size: 14px;
    Margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.two-column {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
.two-column .column {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.contents {
    width: 100%;
}
.two-column .contents {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
}
.two-column img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
.two-column .text {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.three-column {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.three-column .column {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.three-column .contents {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
.three-column img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 180px;
    height: auto;
}
.three-column .text {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.img-align-vertical img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
table[class=hide], img[class=hide], td[class=hide] {
    display: none !important;
}
.contents1 {
    width: 100%;

</style>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {border-collapse: collapse !important;}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body style="Margin:0;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;min-width:100%;background-color:#f3f2f0;">
<center class="wrapper" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;background-color:#f3f2f0;">
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:#f3f2f0;" bgcolor="#f3f2f0;">
    <tr>
      <td width="100%"><div class="webkit" style="max-width:600px;Margin:0 auto;"> 

          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>

                        <table width="100" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing:0" >
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                                <![endif]--> 

          <!-- ======= start main body ======= -->
          <table class="outer" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing:0;Margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:600px;">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;"><!-- ======= start header ======= -->

                <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  >
                  <tr>
                    <td><table style="width:100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center"><center>
                                <table border="0" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="Margin: 0 auto;">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td class="one-column" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><!-- ======= start header ======= -->

                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#f3f2f0">
                                          <tr>
                                            <td class="two-column" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;text-align:left;font-size:0;" >&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </table></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </center></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                <!-- ======= end header ======= --> 

                <!-- ======= start two column ======= -->
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  style=" border-left:1px solid #e8e7e5; border-right:1px solid #e8e7e5">
                  <tr>
                    <td background="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/444a837423b315d2d2f73a03c/images/8ed1174a-8cea-49a4-8010-0c48fb55f96f.png" bgcolor="#000000" width="600" height="240" valign="top" align="center" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;text-align:center;font-size:0" 
class="two-column"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:260px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/444a837423b315d2d2f73a03c/images/8ed1174a-8cea-49a4-8010-0c48fb55f96f.png" color="#1f3ca6" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
                      <div>
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                    <table width="50%" style="border-spacing:0" >
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                                                    <![endif]-->
                        <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:299px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
                          <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="inner" style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:10px;padding-left:30px;"><table class="contents1" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%">
                                <tr>
                                  <td   align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-top:20px; padding-right:30px"><p style="font-size:30px; text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:left">&nbsp;</p>
                                    <p style="font-size:30px; text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:left"><strong>Agenda Internacional</strong></p>
                                    <p style="font-size:14px; text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:left; line-height:18px">Semana de 18 a 22 Fevereiro 2019</p></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                    </td><td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                                                    <![endif]-->
                        <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:299px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;"></div>
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                    </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                    <![endif]-->
                      </div>
                      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]--></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>                <!-- ======= end two column ======= -->
```

Comment: Can you trim your code down to the relevant parts?

Comment: Complex email formatting is the bane of all email newsletters. The best suggestion is to simplify your layout: header, content, dividers, footer. Skip the tables.

Comment: Bruno I would _leave_ all the code in here (it's verbose but relevant), but can you please include a description or screenshots of the intended display vs actual display? This will help isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have one image as a background for two table cells. Instead of fighting against yourself, break the image into two parts. It doesn't look like the second image needs to be in the background. To do this, create a table with two cells

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Agenda Internacional</td>
    <td>*corporate logo*</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

By doing this, you can add a class so that in mobile, the right table cell stacks below the left one. Currently in email clients like Outlook for IOS, iPhone X, the right cell is off-screen.

In gmail and other email clients, the background is repeating. You should add `background-repeat: no-repeat;`.

A good email template to follow to create more dynamic email newsletters is Cerberus. Another good template environment is Zurb Foundation for Email. It has a html for website component as well. I suggest you download one of those and use it as your base. I think you will get a much better product.

- https://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/
- https://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html

Good luck.